# Background image reflection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a background image(`background:url(my_image.jpg) no-repeat;`), and I need a reflection for that picture, you can see here, what I mean: http://www.imgmodels.com/.

Is there a way to do that, using a JS script or css hacks...?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jquery plugin that does it:
http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery

Comment: It doesn't work with `background-image`, I don't know why I don't see the reflection yet. ` $("#hold-picture.contact").reflect({height:0.3,opacity:0.4});`

Comment: I don't think I should be working with a background. What the script probably does is create a div under the reflected image.. and you cannot do it for a background.
Anyway, there is a work around if you want it to be a background: Just use z-index to position it under the element you want to have it as a background

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any css method (only if you crop the image and create a new div below the image, and add a background with css) but you can use jquery [reflection](http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using HTML5 canvas and for IE DirectX filters will help you to achieve the same effect. There is also a pre-made library that solves that for you: http://cow.neondragon.net/stuff/reflection/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css, but unfortunately only properly in Webkit browsers.

See [here](http://webkit.org/blog/182/css-reflections/)